# Different POM Files for production environment

Tags: maven, production-environment, pom.xml

Team here have built the project in test environment and hence pom files have jars used for testing as dependencies.

However, same pom file is being used in production and hence the Jars used for testing are getting into production which is not a good practice.

Question - Is it not possible to have a pom files with the testing jars not listed as dependencies and build the code?

Team here said that it is not possible...

Answer (score 2):

Set a `<scope>` for the dependency, for junit for example we add a dependency like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

From the maven docs http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

> **test** - this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.

Comment: Will the test scope prevent Maven from downloading them... because in this case the files are still being downloaded in production environment ... and aim is to prevent maven from downloading them ... hope this makes sense .. thanks for your answer though

Comment: You are building in production environment? Strange. Why not building artifacts (releasing and deploying) them to a repository manager and transfer them to production.

Comment: Unless you execute a test compilation or execute phase, they wont be downloaded AFAIK, but as @khmarbaise said, you probably shouldn't build in the production environment and just use the builded artifacts...

Answer (score 0):

Are they aware of the difference between src/test/resources and src/main/resources (and src/test/java and src/main/java) which can be used to separate test and production configuration. For this you use the same pom file. Furthermore the dependencies should be defined if they are used for test (test) or if the are used for production code.